# Game Engine Display Problem

Tags: rendering, mesh, game-engine

I'm new to the Blender Game Engine; I've tried to look it up, but no luck. Whenever I play the game, only the default cube is shown, and every other object I create isn't showing. I can't tell much more detail since I don't know too much about the problem, but how do I fix this?

Comment: It will be helpful to add screenshots to your question to help show what you are experiencing,